# Can I visit other countries than the country issuing my visa during my trip to Europe?

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel

I have a Business Class Schengen visa type C, single entry, to Austria. The issuing country is also Austria. I have a few days free in between my meeting dates. I want to travel to other nearby EU countries for one-night stays in each.

Can I do this with the visa I have? If yes, then do I just book a plane ticket and travel. Or do I need some documents for that?

I got only a single-entry visa with a period of stay of 20 days.

I'm traveling first to Austria; then I booked a flight to Paris, France. Is that possible or should I travel only by train or road, since my visa is only single-entry? Can I fly to other Schengen countries with a single-entry visa?

As I have to get back to Austria after my second meeting, can I come back to Austria on a single-entry visa?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, you may not misrepresent your itinerary on your visa application, and if you did not mention side trips to other Schengen countries in your application there may be a *suspicion* that you lied. The easiest way to avoid suspicion is if nobody notices your travel, which may be easier by road than by air. Otherwise make sure that you have documentation of intra-Schengen travel and your meetings in Austria, and keep this for a couple of years.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, enjoy your trip. You do not need any extra documentation. If you are going to Austria for your meeting and after that you have time feel free to roam around the Schengen zone as you please.

You do not need any extra documentation for that. And as long as you remain within the Schengen zone your single entry visa remains valid even if you move from One Schengen country to another Schengen country.

You can take a flight, use a road, take a ship or just walk into another country there is no restriction on the mode of travel within the Schengen zone.